# How to solve jQuery and mootoools conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, mootools, conflict

I use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.2.pack.js"> </script>
```

to load jquery and then load an external script that contains these :

---

```
var jkpanel={
    controltext: 'menu',
    $mainpanel: null, contentdivheight: 0,
    openclose:function($, speed){
    this.$mainpanel.stop() //stop any animation
    if (this.$mainpanel.attr('openstate')=='closed')
        this.$mainpanel.animate({top: 0}, speed).attr({openstate: 'open'})
    else
        this.$mainpanel.animate({top: -this.contentdivheight+'px'}, speed).attr({openstate: 'closed'})
},

init:function(file, height, speed){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        jkpanel.$mainpanel=$('<div id="dropdownpanel"><div class="contentdiv"></div><div class="control">'+jkpanel.controltext+'</div></div>').prependTo('body')
        var $contentdiv=jkpanel.$mainpanel.find('.contentdiv')
        var $controldiv=jkpanel.$mainpanel.find('.control').css({cursor: 'wait'})
        $contentdiv.load(file, '', function($){
                var heightattr=isNaN(parseInt(height))? 'auto' : parseInt(height)+'px'
                $contentdiv.css({height: heightattr})
                jkpanel.contentdivheight=parseInt($contentdiv.get(0).offsetHeight)
                jkpanel.$mainpanel.css({top:-jkpanel.contentdivheight+'px', visibility:'visible'}).attr('openstate', 'closed')
                $controldiv.css({cursor:'hand', cursor:'pointer'})
        })
        jkpanel.$mainpanel.click(function(){jkpanel.openclose($, speed)})       
    })
}
}

//Initialize script: jkpanel.init('path_to_content_file', 'height of content DIV in px', animation_duration)
jkpanel.init('1', '80px', 1000)
```

---

and also use a mootools plugin of course.

**MY QUESTION IS THAT** how should I use `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` in the above script to prevent conflicting

Comment: What, exactly, is the conflict? You've posted a lot of code, but not really described what problem(s) you're seeing.

Comment: I want to use a dropdown panel with jquery base in my template and meanwhile using a mootools photoslider ( a joomla component) in my site . so the photo slider don't show any image while i load this jquery script in my page

Answer (score 5):

Wrap all the JavaScript that relies on jQuery in a closure to prevent namespace conflicts, like so:

```
// Start closure to prevent namespace conflicts
;(function($) {

  // Whatever code you want that relies on $ as the jQuery object

// End closure
})(jQuery);
```

It looks weird, but the syntax is right (yes, the first line starts with a semicolon). This automatically substitutes `jQuery` for the `$` object, which both jQuery and mootools make use of. Since you're using both, you should wrap all of your jQuery code in a closure like this (one for each .js file or `script` tag).

Comment: Why does the first line start with a semicolon? Also: as far as I can tell, all of the jQuery code in the question *is* wrapped in code like this: it's all in the ready callback, which gets (and uses) jQuery as its parameter.

Comment: I've been confused and code does not work. can you please give me final code with the fix from the code I insert above?

Comment: btw, you can do exactly the same for mootools 1.2.3+, just replace last 
})(jQuery) 
with 
})(document.id)

Comment: what is document.id dear Mike? 

I'm so new to jquery , please integrate my script above with the noConflict(); function and give me final code

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is just, you load MooTools, and then you load jQuery, and then MooTools doesn't work because jQuery has taken over the dollar function, then you probably just need code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.2.pack.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

That should get jQuery to relinquish `$()`. The code you have in your question already does the other handy thing, which is use the parameter to the ready event handler as a way to locally use a shorter name for the `jQuery` object.

I'd strongly recommend reading the [jQuery page on working with other libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) and maybe the documentation for the [`noConflict()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict) function.